# Intent just return partial object when startAtivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I have to class `book` and `author`. And `book` class contain an `author` array. I start an add book activity from main activity by using `startActivityForResult`. In the sub-activity, I build an author array, and ensure that it contain the author object just initialized. Then pass it back. This is the code:

```
Log.d("djdjdjjdjdjdjdjdjdj", authors[0].firstName);//could display the firstName;

intent.putExtra("book", new Book(title, authors, isbn, price));
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
finish();
```

In this case the LogCat could display the first name.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode == ADD_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
            Book book = (Book) data.getParcelable("book");
            Log.d("JJJJJJJJJJJJ", book.getTitle());//could display the title;
            Log.d("UUUUUUUUUUUU", book.getAuthors()[0].firstName);//NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array;
            shoppingCart.add(book);
            viewHolderAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

When come back to main Activity and extract `book` object, it contain title but author array. Why?
Here is the book class:

```
public class Book implements Parcelable{

public String title;
public Author[] authors;
public String isbn;
public String price;

public Book(String title, Author[] authors, String isbn, String price) {

    this.title = title;
    this.authors = authors;
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.price = price;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public Author[] getAuthors()
{
    return authors;
}
public String getIsbn()
{
    return isbn;
}
public String getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

public int describeContents(){
    return 0;
}

public Book(Parcel in)
{
    Parcelable[] parcelableArray =
            in.readParcelableArray(Author.class.getClassLoader());
    Author[] authors = null;
    if (parcelableArray != null) {
        authors = Arrays.copyOf(parcelableArray, parcelableArray.length, Author[].class);
    }

    this.title = in.readString();
    this.isbn = in.readString();
    this.price = in.readString();
}

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeParcelableArray(authors, flags);
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeString(isbn);
    dest.writeString(price);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
    authors = in.createTypedArray(Author.CREATOR);
    title = in.readString();
    isbn = in.readString();
    price = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Book> CREATOR
        = new Parcelable.Creator<Book>() {
    public Book createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Book(in);
    }

    public Book[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Book[size];
    }
};
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your Book class

Comment: [Take a look](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/)

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the Book class constructor:

```
Parcelable[] parcelableArray =
        in.readParcelableArray(Author.class.getClassLoader());
Author[] authors = null;
if (parcelableArray != null) {
    authors = Arrays.copyOf(parcelableArray, parcelableArray.length, Author[].class);
}
```

You have created the `authors` variable, assigned `null` to it and copied the parsed array to it. But you should assing `Book` class variable instead.

Just remove the string `Author[] authors = null;` and your code will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I manage answer my own question with another solution...
I just replace:

```
Parcelable[] parcelableArray =
    in.readParcelableArray(Author.class.getClassLoader());
Author[] authors = null;
if (parcelableArray != null) {
    authors = Arrays.copyOf(parcelableArray, parcelableArray.length, Author[].class);
}
```

with:

```
authors = in.createTypedArray(Author.CREATOR);
```

and replace:

```
dest.writeParcelableArray(authors, flags);
```

with:

```
dest.writeTypedArray(authors, flags);
```